# Выравнивание колонок

Tags: html, css, flexbox, float, выравнивание

Не  могу выровнять средний столбец. Пробовал флексами  и `space-between` - криво выходит. Флотами тоже не  получается . Надо чтобы левый  и правый столбец были  выравнены  по  краям контейнера. А средний  был  чётко  в центре.

```css
.items ul:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
}

.items ul:nth-child(2) {
  float: right;
}

.items ul:nth-child(3) {
  float: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="items cfix">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item1"></div><span>Оформление<br>документов</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item2"></div><span>Бальзамирование</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item3"></div><span>Катафалк</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item4"></div><span>Бригада</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item5"></div><span>Копка</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item6"></div><span>Отпевание<br>в церкви</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item7"></div><span>Поминальный<br>обряд</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item8"></div><span>Кремация</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item9"></div><span>Груз 200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте стили своих попыток выровнять. Лучше всего - сделайте по действующему примеру кода на каждую из попыток. Чтобы увидеть, как у вас получилось, и подумать, что поправить.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
}

.items * {
  margin: 5px;
}

.items {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  width: 30%;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  background: gray;
  text-align: right;
}

div {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="items cfix">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item1">Foto</div><span>Оформление документов</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item2">Foto</div><span>Бальзамирование</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item3">Foto</div><span>Катафалк</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item4">Foto</div><span>Бригада</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item5">Foto</div><span>Копка</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item6">Foto</div><span>Отпеваниев церкви</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item7">Foto</div><span>Поминальный обряд</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item8">Foto</div><span>Кремация</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item9">Foto</div><span>Груз 200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробовал сделать выравнивание с помощью flexbox. По-моему, все ровно, посмотрите сами. 
https://codepen.io/dimkadenisov/pen/LJbEMX

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items cfix">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item1"></div>             <span>Оформление<br>документов</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item2"></div><span>Бальзамирование</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item3"></div><span>Катафалк</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item4"></div><span>Бригада</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item5"></div><span>Копка</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item6"></div><span>Отпевание<br>в церкви</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item7"></div><span>Поминальный<br>обряд</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item8"></div><span>Кремация</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item9"></div><span>Груз 200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Данный пример не учитывает, что ширина флекс элементов, в данном случае, зависит от контента https://jsfiddle.net/l2banners/32cy416h/

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант при помощи `display: grid;`

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10%;
}

.items ul {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.items ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="items cfix">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item1"></div><span>Оформление<br>документов</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item2"></div><span>Бальзамирование</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item3"></div><span>Катафалк</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item4"></div><span>Бригада</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item5"></div><span>Копка</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item6"></div><span>Отпевание<br>в церкви</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="item7"></div><span>Поминальный<br>обряд</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item8"></div><span>Кремация</span></li>
    <li>
      <div class="item9"></div><span>Груз 200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пробежался по ответам... и перечитал вопрос... `flex`, `grid`, `float`...

А что, просто `position` для таких задач уже не в моде? Работает же! Добавлю вариант:

```css
.items {
  position: relative;
}

.items ul {
  position: absolute;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.items ul:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.items ul:nth-child(3) {
  right: 0;
}

.items img {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.items span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="items cfix">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="item1"></div><img src=""><span>Оформление<br>документов</span></li>
    <li><div class="item2"></div><img src=""><span>Бальзамирование</span></li>
    <li><div class="item3"></div><img src=""><span>Катафалк</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="item4"></div><img src=""><span>Бригада</span></li>
    <li><div class="item5"></div><img src=""><span>Копка</span></li>
    <li><div class="item6"></div><img src=""><span>Отпевание<br>в церкви</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div class="item7"></div><img src=""><span>Поминальный<br>обряд</span></li>
    <li><div class="item8"></div><img src=""><span>Кремация</span></li>
    <li><div class="item9"></div><img src=""><span>Груз 200</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```